# Problems with "ImageView cell width" on tablelayout

Tags: android

I'm having troubles when tray to insert some images in a tablerow of tablelayout.

The first imageview expands the width of its own cell and the next images expands the rest of the row

How can i divide de row in five cells with equal size?

This is a snapshot of app

http://i41.tinypic.com/2dv77g6.png

This is the code of xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ES_user"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/ES_user"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/User"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/ES_logout"
            android:textColor="#fc0505"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/ES_logo"
                    android:paddingRight="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logotra" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Textpatient"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/ES_codpatient"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                     <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/TxtCodPatient"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:inputType="text" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ESlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/esp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ENlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/en" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/CATlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/GAlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/ga" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/EUlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/eusk" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/PTlanguagebtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.166"
                            android:src="@drawable/por" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/BtnStart"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text="@string/ES_start" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/large_appname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ES_large_appname"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding android:stretchColumns="*" into your TableView

Comment: Try to remove `android:gravity="center_vertical|right"` and set `Linearlayout` gravity as `android:gravity="left"`.

Comment: @coelho this expands the white table to match screen size, this not works for me :(

Comment: @GrIsHu this gravity property only changes the align of the user tittle, thanks

Comment: @Hanzo besides setting the image into `src` set it as `background` of your `ImageView` as `android:background="@drawable/user"`.

Comment: @GrIsHu the problem is in the country flags row, not in the user ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the layout of your 5 country images as below:

As you are giving your each `ImageView` weight then to get the best result you must have to give width of the `ImageView` as `0dp`.

Replace your 5 country code with below code and check out.

> ```
>          <TableRow
>                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                     android:layout_weight="1" >
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/ESlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:background="@drawable/icon" />
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/ENlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:src="@drawable/icon" />
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/CATlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:src="@drawable/icon" />
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/GAlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:src="@drawable/icon" />
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/EUlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:src="@drawable/icon" />
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/PTlanguagebtn"
>                         android:layout_width="0dp"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>                         android:layout_weight="0.166"
>                         android:src="@drawable/icon" />
>                 </TableRow>
> ```

Let me know if still any problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this works fine for me, PLease, Can you explain me why is necessary assign "0dp" to each imageview?

Comment: LinearLayout supports assigning a weight to individual children. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view, and allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Default weight is zero. View elements with weight not specified (no weight entry) get weight 0 which means they get no expansion.

Comment: if we set to 0 dip the value of the dimension which we are playing with (width in this example) we are telling the system to not to take care about the content but to focus on the whole size of the element, having an equitable distribution of our elements according to our weight values.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

to this

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: This linear layout only contains a user name an "logout button" not works for me, thanks